# Let $a=2e_1+3e_2-4e_3$ and $b=e_1-e_2+3e_3$. Find a vector c such that $ac=3-17e_1\land e_2-e_2\land e_3-22e_3\land e_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

$(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is a positively oriented orthonormal frame.
$ac=a \cdot c+ a\land c$.
Am I doing a geometric product of the vector and trivectors?
I do not know what to do with b

Comment: and the vector $b$ is not useful?

Comment: That is where I am stuck at but using the formula ac, can I incorporate b into the process?

Comment: I edited it correctly for ac. I dont know what to do with b

Answer (score 0):

we call $c =(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and $a=(2,3,-4)$
$$$$
then $ac=3+(-1,-22,-17)$
and the dot produt will be:
$$a\cdot c=2c_1+3c_2-4c_3=3$$
and the cross product is:
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc} e_1&e_2&e_3\\
2&3&-4\\
c_1&c_2&c_3\end{array}\right|=(3c_3+4c_2)e_1+(-4c_1-2c_3)e_2+(2c_2-3c_3)e_3$$
this imply the nexts equalities:$3c_3+4c_2=-1$ ;$-4c_1-2c_3=-22$ and $2c_2-3c_3=-17$
$$$$
now we write $c_2$ and $c_3$ in function of $c_1$
$$c_3=-11+2c_1$$
$$c_2=\frac{-17+c_3}{2}$$
replacing that in the dot product:
$$2c_2+3(-11+2c_1)-4(\frac{-17+c_3}{2})=3$$ 
$$2c_1-33+6c_1+34-6c_1=3=>c_1=1$$
use this value in the formulas using above:
$$c_2=-11+2=-9$$
$$c_3=\frac{-17+3}{2}=-7$$
finally the vector $c$ is:
$$c=(1,-9,-7)$$

Comment: 1st question, how did you come up with ac=3+(-1,-22,-17)?

Comment: I do not understand how can you determine what is c in the ac equation and what is a in that same equation

Comment: because $e_i\land e_j=e_k$

Comment: for example $-17e_1\land e_2=-17e_3 -e_2\land e_3=-e_1 -22e_3\land e_1=-22e_2$ then you have $-e_1-22e_2-17e_3=(-1,-22,-17)$ is other notation for the same vector

Comment: How can you switch $e_1$ and $e_3$? what property did you use?

Comment: I thought $e_1\land e_2 = I$

Comment: wait a minute, the symbol $\land$ denote the cross product?????

Comment: $\land$ means wedge

Comment: sorry, i am a stupid

Comment: Its okay bro. thanks